# Clustering text using 3 different approches (MinHash, HAC, K-means)

Tags: data-mining, k-means, text-mining, levenshtein-distance, hierarchical-clustering

I have a set of university courses (around 30000). Each course have the following attributes, here is an example:

- **Title:** Machine Learning
- **Institution name:** Department of Information Technology
- **Description:** After the course the student should be able to: set up and solve typical machine learning problems, by implementation or
  with simulation tools, determine different learning methods
  applicability for different types of learning problems, ie know the
  methods strengths and weaknesses, set a good representation of the
  data, recognize the typical effects of bad choices and determine how
  to improve the results and describe how and why the machine learning
  and natural computation methods.\

I want to cluster these courses to help users with suggestions on similar courses that they liked or searched for. An example would be if a user is searching for "Machine learning" the system could suggest "Artificial intelligence" since the content of those courses are a little bit similar. I am thinking of three different approaches to do this.

1. TF-IDF + spherical K-means
2. levenstein similarity + hierarchical agglomerative clustering
3. Jaccard similarity + minhash + locality sensitive hashing (LSH)

My plan is to try this methods in Matlab, come up with the best one and eventually (if I have time enough) implement it. I am planning to do this as my master thesis, all information on this would be highly appreciated. Does it make sense to compare this three methods on the given dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the data available somewhere?